# Is there a way to impersonate a service account with the cloudsql_proxy executable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy

I have found this is possible by setting impersonation system wide with this command: `gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account <MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>`.

The proxy exe seems to read the gcloud config.

But that is really clunky. I want to start the proxy and specify a specific user to impersonate without having to change it system wide. Also, I'm not resorting to generating non-expiring json keys- I want to use impersonation.

Many Gcloud commands now support a specific switch for this, but the proxy exe does not. See this GitHub issue (with no response from google): https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/417

Can I run `gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account=<MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT>` and set an env var the proxy exe will pick up or something?

I can't find anything in the code except this mention of gcloud: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/blob/eca37935e7cd54efcd612c170e46f45c1d8e3556/cmd/cloud_sql_proxy/cloud_sql_proxy.go#L160

> - When the gcloud command-line tool is installed on the local
>   machine, the
>   "active account" is used for authentication. Run 'gcloud auth list' to see
>   which accounts are installed on your local machine and
>   'gcloud config list account' to view the active account.

which is funny because when running `auth/impersonate_service_account` `gcloud config list account` doesn't say anything about it.

Is there a way to have Gcloud do impersonation on a per session basis?

EDIT: just to follow up, per the answer the `--token` totally works, so now I can run the proxy with IAM auth and impersonation a gsa simultaneously:

```
# start proxy with IAM login as a GSA with a cloud sql service account setup
./cloud_sql_proxy \
    -enable_iam_login \
    -dir=/var/run/cloudsql \
    -instances=project_id:region:instance_name \
    --token=$(gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account='my-gsa@myco.iam.gserviceaccount.com')

# now can auth through proxy as cloud sql federated user 
psql "sslmode=disable \
    host='/var/run/cloudsql/project_id:region:instance_name' \
    user=my-gsa@myco.iam dbname=mydb"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of Cloud SQL Proxy (≥ 2.0) have explicit support for impersonation, so things now work a bit differently from the previous answers:

```
cloud-sql-proxy --impersonate-service-account=<service-account> <instance-connection-name>
```

or if you prefer:

```
CSQL_PROXY_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=<service-account> cloud-sql-proxy <instance-connection-name>
```

Comment: Just want to add a link to docs, I could only find an example in the cli help output: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy/blob/main/cmd/root.go#L209

Comment: We'll add a page to the public docs. Meanwhile, the Proxy's help command will provide all the necessary details. Note this is a v2 feature.

Answer (score 8):

I found this trick with the `--token` parameter

```
cloud_sql_proxy --instances=<instanceName>=tcp:3306 \
  --token=$(gcloud auth print-access-token --impersonate-service-account=<service account>)
```

Comment: yes perfect! I'm adding a note about iam auth to my post as well

Comment: @red888 - If you are concerned about using credential files, then this solution will work but is even more insecure. The CLI stores credentials in well-known locations. Additionally, the CLI auth application-default login credentials are **user account** credentials. You should only use a service account with the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy (quota limitations). Do not pre-authorize the CLI on production systems e.g. after a login session, revoke the credentials. In this set up a hacker not only has user credentials to toy with but the ability to impersonate other credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Set CLOUDSDK_AUTH_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT variable, like this:

```
CLOUDSDK_AUTH_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=<your serviceaccount> ./cloud_sql_proxy \
    -enable_iam_login \
    -dir=/var/run/cloudsql \
    -instances=project_id:region:instance_name
```

Comment: Holy cow is this new!? Does CLOUDSDK_AUTH_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT also work with the gcp SDKs? If I set this var and run GCP SDK code will it run the code in the security context of the CLOUDSDK_AUTH_IMPERSONATE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT user? Or is this just for cloud_sql_proxy and the gcloud cli?

Comment: I want to mark this as an answer, but I'm not able to test and can't seem to find official docs for this. Can you link to official docs?

Comment: This is part of a general way to set gcloud config using environment variables, documented here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties#setting_properties_using_environment_variables. cloudsql proxy uses gcloud under the hood to extract the configuration using "gcloud config config-helper"